# Is this systemd service running or not?

Tags: systemd

When we re-deploy an application we use `systemd restart` to restart the application. It would seem that either `systemd restart` or `systemd status` (or both) are unreliable.

1. Sometimes `systemd restart` DOESN'T restart the application and doesn't throw an error. PID is the same as before and the old version of the app is still running. Is `restart` effective immediately?
2. Sometimes `systemd restart` does kill the old process and start the new process but `systemd status` shows the service as dead. We see the process running as a child of systemd.

As an example of the 2nd problem: `systemctl status` is says the service inactive(dead) but it's definitely running (new pids 25548 and 25551)!

```
$systemctl status gateway.service
gateway.service - The API Gateway - Nginx
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gateway.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2020-08-05 14:00:16 CEST; 1h 43min ago
  Process: 25545 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25542 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25540 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /daten/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 25545 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 130.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/gateway.service
           ├─25548 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf
           └─25551 nginx: worker process
```

`ps | grep nginx` shows the 2 nginx processes:

```
nginx      25548              root    5u  IPv4 58124367      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
nginx      25551             nginx    5u  IPv4 58124367      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

`pstree` shows these 2 processes as children of systemd:

```
systemd─┬...
        ├─nginx───nginx
```

### systemd Config

```
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/daten/nginx.pid

# Nginx will fail to start if /run/nginx.pid already exists but has the wrong
# SELinux context. This might happen when running `nginx -t` from the cmdline.
# https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1268621
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /daten/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx  -c /prg/nginx/conf/gateway.conf

KillSignal=QUIT
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=process
PrivateTmp=true
```

Comment: I generally use `systemctl` or `service` to manage my applications, but they all do the same thing. Check out `journalctl -xe` for more details on the start process. An application I recently installed didn't have rw permissions to its own directory because of a mistake I made transferring my cache backup. It showed as inactive but was still running, yet couldn't do anything. Your issue may be similar. Post the output of the above immediately after attempting a restart if you still need help.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the KillSignal should be `SIGQUIT` and not `QUIT`.
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html
It also looks like `SIGHUP` would reload the config without a restart...
http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html

Comment: Yeah, `killall -s HUP nginx` seems to reload the config nicely.